# Select count(id) from one table where that id is present in another table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

**EDIT: Detailed description**

***Detailed Description:***

*in table_a there are 100 members but only 50 of them have records in table_b and only 25 have records in table_b where approved = 1 THEREFORE the value I will need returned by the query is 25*

Hey everyone here is the query I am trying to resolve it will need to return a single result count so I can access with mysql_result($query, 0).

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_a WHERE (THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK)
```

I need to check if the( count of memberID in table_b WHERE memberID matching each id in table_a and approved in table_b = 1) - is greater than 1

The final result needs to be a count of the number of members that have an entry in table_b.

Sample of table columns that need to access

```
table_a
-----------------
id

table_b
------------------
id
memberID
approved
```

Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: ok are you looking for the ID in table a greater than 1 or in both tables greater than 1?

Comment: Is it correct to say the result should be the number of rows in a that have a corresponding entry in b where (a.id = b.memberId and b.approved = 1)?

Comment: @ukritic - Are your final needs to return the "count(table_a.id = table_b.MemberID AND table_b.approved = 1)" value, and only if that count is ">1"?

Comment: Here is the best way to psudo code the statement "I need to SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_a WHERE eachID in table_a has an entry in table_b matched to memberID in table_b and approved = 1 in table_b" THe final result should be a single row with COUNT(id) = ##

Answer (score 3):

**Problem Solved**

Had to think of it backwards

```
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT memberID )
    FROM table_b
    WHERE approved =1
```

I do not need to even look at table_a seeing as I am counting the memberID based on table_b

Sometimes the solution is so simple and right in front of you.

Thanks for all the help! I hope this helps other in the future.

Comment: This is the same as your question specification with one tiny but crucial detail: Any value of `table_b.memberid` also appears in `table_a.id`. Which off course no-one can know, if you don't tell them.

Comment: this query returns the result I am looking for. Basically I do not need to query table_a because I only need a count of the DISTINCT memberID's from table_b. After I rethought what information I really needed it became clear to me that table_a was not needed in the query.

Comment: Yes, I meant that it is correct. Also removed the unneeded parentheses after `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to get the number of records in table_a that match to table_b, as long as the value in table_b is approved.  Therefore, I would join the 2 tables.  The inner join ensures that you only consider rows that are in both tables, and the where statement takes care of the approved requirement.

```
select count(a.id) 
from table_a a
join table_b b
on a.id = b.memberID
where b.approved=1
```

Comment: This returns the wrong number looks like it returns the total number of items found in table_b not the total from table_a that meet the requirements.

Comment: I think this would be correct if you changed `COUNT(a.id)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT b.ID, a.ID 

 FROM table_a a, table_b b 

 WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND b.ID = 1
```

Comment: According to the OP, he needs entries where "...approved in table_b = 1".  ie, b.APPROVED = 1, whereas you have b.ID = 1.

Comment: Agreed with @sharakan - the test is for "table_b.approved" = 1, not "b.ID".

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty in SQL, but can this be achieved by specifying the two tables in the query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_a.id) 
  FROM table_a, table_b 
  WHERE table_a.id = table_b.MemberID 
    AND table_b.approved = 1;
```

I believe that meets your select criteria.

Comment: this returns the same number from above what looks like the total count of table_b records and not the count of table_a records that meets the criteria

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM table_a AS a
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM table_b AS b
        WHERE b.memberID = a.id
          AND b.approved = 1
      )
```